# How can I put a variable in a input value

Tags: html, select, input

I need to put a variable in the "value" field and you can change the selected value from "select". How can I do it? Thx.

Comment: Can you please add your code that you have tried till now?

Comment: we need either more explanation of your software or an example of your code in which you are trying to do this. Then we can help you

Comment: HTML itself doesn't have any notion of "variables". You'll need to provide more context and explanation here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Jquery?

For example you have input like

```
<input type="text" id="example" value="">
```

Then you have a select like this

```
<select id="options_example" name="options">
<option value="1">1</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

With Javascript/Jquery :

//get the option selected

```
var selected = $('#options_example').val()
```

Modify the value of the input

```
$("#example").val(selected)
```

Hope this helps

Best